# Use of "en" in "Ça en intéresse certains"

Tags: questions, en

I understand the sentences

```
Ça t'intéresse.
Je m'intéresse à la littérature française.
```

But what's the use/meaning of the word `"en"` in the following sentence?

```
Ça en intéresse quelqu'un?
```

Does it replace a COD? Is it a fixed expression?

Comment: Where did you find this? Can you provide the context?

Answer (score 4):

The grammar is quite loose, especially if the singular *quelqu'un* is used, but this "***en***" refers to the person(s) interested in what is being discussed.

e.g. ([wikipedia discussion](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Wikid%C3%A9mie/ao%C3%BBt_2016)):

> ...soit ça n’intéresse pas les lecteurs, soit, **si ça en intéresse quelqu’un**, ça ne peut l’intéresser que pour savoir pour chaque mot si ça y est ou pas.

***Quelqu'un des lecteurs*** is definitely not academic.

It is much more usual with a plural:

> ***Ça en intéresse quelques-uns.*** → Quelques-uns (de ceux dont ont parle) sont intéressés par ça.

or the sentence of your title:

> ***Ça en intéresse certains ?***  → Est-ce que certains (d'entre-vous) sont intéressés par ça ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse *Quelques-uns/certains*. Le pronom est redondant. On aurait pu dire: *Ça en intéresse ?*

Comment: Selon le contexte, le "en" peut aussi remplacer un complément du pronom "certains" our "quelqu'uns". P.ex: "ça intéresse certains des élèves" => "ça en intéresse certains". "ça intéresse quelques-uns d'entre nous" => "ça en intéresse quelques-uns".

Comment: "Quelqu'un des gens" serait effectivement incorrect, mais on peux mettre un complément avec les pluriel "quelques-un(e)s", pour préciser de quel groupe ces "quelques-uns" font partie: ex: quelques-uns d'entre nous, quelques-uns de mes amis, quelques-uns des professeurs, quelques-unes de mes oeuvres, etc.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse *Quelqu'un des gens* n'est pas totalement exclu si gens est qualifié. On peut entendre par exemple l'euphémisme « quelqu'un des gens du voyage » ou « L’hôtesse le voyant si laid & mal en conche, présuma que ce fust quelqu’un des gens du Capitaine qui eût été là envoyé devant, si lui fit fendre bragardement du bois. » [Dictionnaire historique de l'ancien langage](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_historique_de_l%E2%80%99ancien_langage_fran%C3%A7ois/Prospectus,_1756)

Comment: Bien vu, je le reconnais en effet avec un complément, sonne un peu vieux.